# Write value on subselect SQL query column in dbgrid

Tags: sql, oracle11g, delphi-7, dbgrid, zeos

I need a join table from table 1 and table 2 and be able to apply updates on it so here's my SQL:

```
select 
    table1.ackode, tabble1.ket,
    table1.debet, table1.kredit, 
    (select table2.ket from table2  
     where table2.kode = table1.ackode 
       and table2.ptlokasi = table1.ptlokasi) as x 
from table1;
```

This resulted in a dbgrid like this :

[image]

now, whenever I click on ackode column, it'll open another form which I can select data from it. I wanted ACKODE and X column changed according to data values I've selected in that new form. However, it raised error as X column cannot be written.
is there any idea how to make it possible? I've set the X column's readonly property to false, however no such luck.
Thanks.

Comment: I have no idea about the dbgrid you are using and whether it supports updates like this, but what I would try is changing the correlated sub query you have to get table2.ket into a simple join between table1 and table2.

Comment: @TomC applyupdates won't work in joined tables but I figured out a way for this. I simply created a calcfield. Thanks for your input!

Comment: Your query is not a joined table, it just fetches a value thru a subquery. Anyway what dataset are you using ? You might get this done by setting the ProviderFlags of X to false and Readonly to false at the same time

Comment: @GuidoG I know I'm not joining table. Readonly is already set to false but it doesn't work. however, I solved my needs with calcfield. Thanks for the idea!